# How to bring Admin Bar in a wordpress theme?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I created a wordpress theme from scratch in wordpress. After I have completed a simple layout, it renders pretty good. But it is not showing the admin bar. I see the top margin, where the admin bar should be but no admin bar.

How to bring the admin bar? I think I missed some snippets, while making the theme?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

have you added the wp_footer()-function to your theme? That is what calls for the admin bar.
So, in your footer.php, you should have something like this:

```
<div>
    <?php wp_footer(); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

First Go to your header.php and Use this code `<?php wp_head(); ?>` Just before the head tag

Then Go to your footer.php and use this code `<?php wp_footer(); ?>` before the  tag.

That's will work pretty.